# How to detect if one of the arguments of a key defined by \pgfkeys has been given value

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

I define a key `test` who has two arguments by `/.code n args` from `\pgfkeys`. Please see the code below.

Now, I want to detect if `#2` has been given a value, but causes error.

So, my questions are:

(1)How to detect if one of the arguments of a key defined by \pgfkeys has been given value?

(2)How to allocate a default value to a argument of key?

**Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{test/.code args={#1[#2]}{\ifx#2\empty \parbox{#1}{blank}\else\parbox{#1}{#2}\fi}}

\pgfkeys{test=1in} % My intension is: if #2 is not given, its default value is "blank".

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use two keys, but you can do it by processing the value later.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{test/.code={\myparbox{#1}}}

\newcommand{\myparbox}[1]{\myparboxauxa#1[]\myparboxauxa}
\def\myparboxauxa#1[#2]#3\myparboxauxa{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax
    \parbox{#1}{blank}%
  \else
    \parbox{#1}{#2}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

X\pgfkeys{test=1in}X

X\pgfkeys{test=1in[something]}X

\end{document}
```

[image]